# How many natural divisors of $8!$ are not divisible by any number from the group of the numbers $\{6,10,12,21\}$?

Tags: combinatorics

How many natural divisors of $8!$ are not divisible by any number from the group of the numbers $\{6,10,12,21\}$?

I am really thinking hard on this one but I'm just in my first steps in cominatorics =\

I tried the inclusion exclusion principle but something just not right in my answers. Can you explain that one?

Please hide the answer so i will have the chance to get it by my own.

Comment: Inclusion-exclusion is a good technique to use here.  Also, note that any number that's divisible by 12 is also divisible by 6, and conversely any number that's not divisible by 6 is also not divisible by 12. So you could ask the same question with the set $\{ 6, 10, 21 \}$ and get the same result.

Comment: i try once again and got 25 as solution i think that its incorrect =\

Comment: You should edit the question to include your solution, so that we can see where you may have gone wrong.

Comment: Let $A$ to be the set of all natural numbers 
which divides at least one of the $6,10,12,21$  ; now use ***inclusion-exclusion principle*** to find $|A|$.

Comment: I try that 
S0= be the number of divisors of 8! (that 96)
and then i created 3 statments A1 be the divisors of 6(that 16) A2 be the divisors of 10(that 9) A3 =be the divisors of 21 (that 4)
and after the calc 
S0-S1+S2-S3 what i got was 25 =\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, first step, establish the divisors of $8!$:

$8!=8\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1 = 2^7\cdot 3^2\cdot 5\cdot 7$

Then there are $(7+1)(2+1)(1+1)(1+1) = 96$ factors in total.

We can find the count of numbers divisible by $6$, for example, by segregating $2\cdot 3$ from the decomposition above and counting factors in the remaining prime decomposition: $ 2^6\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7$, giving $56$ factors divisible by $6$.

Similarly there are:
- $42$ factors divisible by $10$
- $32$ factors divisible by $21$
- $48$ factors divisible by $12$ (which are all also divisible by $6$, so we do not need to track these)

In the same way, we can find the count of factors that are divisible by both $6$ and $10$ - meaning they are divisible by $30$.  These will be double-counted if we subtracted all the above values off the total factor count, so would need adding back in, and similarly for other pairings. Then this process would have wrongly added back the set divisible by all three factors under consideration, so that needs subtraction again to complete the inclusion-exclusion process.

- $28$ factors divisible by $ \text{lcm}(6,10) = 30$
- $28$ factors divisible by $ \text{lcm}(6,21) =42$
- $14$ factors divisible by $ \text{lcm}(10,21) = 210 $
- $14$ factors divisible by $ \text{lcm}(6,10,21) = 210 $  (the same as above of course)

Via an inclusion-exclusion process, we can thus determine the number of factors of $8!$ not divisible by any member of the given set:

> $96 - (56+42+32) + (28+28+14) - 14 = \fbox{$22\,$}$

Answer (score 2):

The answer is $22$. I tried to explain in the simplest way I could find: using sets.

Hope it can help

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, you can ignore $12$ because any number divisible by $12$ is already divisible by $6$.  Your count of $96$ divisors of $8!$ is correct, but your count of those divisible by $6$ is not.  You just need to count the divisors of $\frac {8!}6$.  Once you subtract S1, S2, and S3, you have subtracted the numbers that are divisible by both $6$ and $10$ twice, once in S1 and once in S2, so you need to add them back in.  That is where inclusion/exclusion comes in.